# Excel US/UK Date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset that I am working on in excel.The data contains US and UK dates. Some of the US dates are for example, m/dd/yyyy and some are mm/dd/yyyy whilst the UK format is dd/mm/yyyy.

How can I change all to the UK format.

Answer (score 0):

Select all the cells in the sheet that contain dates and run:

```
Sub UK()
    Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
End Sub
```

The action can also be performed manually.
*(If required, the macro could also find all the date cells for you)*:

```
Sub konvert()
    Dim cell As Range, usa As String, uk As String

    usa = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    uk = "dd/mm/yyyy"

    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If cell.NumberFormat = usa Then cell.NumberFormat = uk
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the date format in this page. 
[image]

or if you are in Windows/Mac, you can change the regional setting to UK
[image]